# Odd button has thicker border but same FlatAppearance

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two buttons:

[image: buttons]

They have exactly the same FlatStyle and FlatAppearance properties set:

[image: FlatStyle = Flat]

I've checked all other properties and they are identical except for BackColor, Text, and Location which is to be expected.

Neither of those buttons are hovered in the screenshot.

Why does "Confirm" have a thicker white border when the application is running? I don't see this thick border in the designer. I don't do anything to these properties in code.

If I change both buttons' FlatStyle to System it looks like this:

[image: FlatStyle = System]

You can see that now "Confirm" has a blue border that "Cancel" doesn't. Where is this coming from?

Comment: That presumably indicates that it has focus. Press `Tab` and see if it moves to the other `Button`.

Comment: Or it's the Form's `AcceptButton`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That was it! Super weird though because it never used to happen. I only noticed it recently and I hadn't been changing anything on that form, not sure why it suddenly started getting focus when the form loaded (it's TabIndex was 3).

Comment: You can set TapStop = false; to your button to prevent that. You will not be able to press Tab to reach it and it will be not selected at start.

Comment: If you want to ensure that no control has focus on load but can still receive focus via the `Tab` key, set the form's `ActiveControl` property to `Nothing` in the `Shown` event handler.

Comment: @Jimi, I was thinking that but then I thought not because the OP said the two `Buttons'` properties were the same. Now it occurs to me that `AcceptButton` is a property of the form, so that seems a distinctly possible cause.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I thought of that because I didn't see a FocusRectangle on the Button. So, it was another possible cause.